# "I cannot draw this picture" in passive voice — use "can" or "could"?

Tags: passive-voice

I am confused by these alternatives:

> 1. This picture cannot be drawn by me
> 2. This picture could not be drawn by me

Comment: The second is related to the active clause "I could not draw this picture."  Neither of the passive versions is particularly idiomatic, though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is difference between "Can", "Could", "Will", "Would", "Shall", and "Should"?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5251/what-is-difference-between-can-could-will-would-shall-and-should)

Comment: I noticed in some grammar site that in active/passive voice conversion,modals are not changing.Hence I think first option seems to be correct.

Comment: The difference is the same as the difference between:  "I am not able to draw the picture" and "I was not able to draw the picture"

Answer (score 2):

The passive voice does not change the tense. Therefore, option 1 is correct.